# ibm mobilefirst platform foundation enterprise vs ibm mobilefirst platform foundation

Tags: mfp

Anyone knows what's the difference between enterprise and non-enterprise edition?

Saw 2 version of IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation when trying to download via Passport Advantage.

Thanks,
yongjin

Answer (score 0):

Important difference is in licensing . You can pay for licensing and avail IBM enterprise support with the enterprise editions . The enterprise edition should also come with better security and more features and options especially on the server side components. The exact features that will be available in the enterprise edition varies with the mobilefirst platform versions. This link [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html) explains the different editions. You should check each version documentation to get a better understanding.